# Issue on Formatting Highcharts.js yAxis Value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can you please let me know how I can yaxis value of the chart at <kbd>[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/HBLCJ/2/)</kbd> As you can see from the example I Used following formater function

```
  labels: {
            formatter: function () {
            return this.value;
   },
```

in yAxis to get rid of the default numericSymbols ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E'] byt this also make the numbers to be too long.  so I tried the

```
 format: '{value:.5f}'
```

to reduce the integer numbers but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you are expecting to be displayed on your y-axis. Do you want to end up with '100K' ? '100000' ? '100000.00000' ?

Comment: sorry for confution karlipoppins, what I would like to have is having 100 instead of 100,000 or 100,000 instead of 100,000,000. Eliminating 3 zeros form the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your comments you want to have 100 instead of 100000...

How about simply this:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
        return this.value / 1000;
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is to modified the following:

```
    tickInterval: 50000,
    max: 200000
```

see updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/HBLCJ/4/

Comment: Thanks ignacio but I do not want to change the max and tickInterval values since I am gettin much bigger numbers dynamically from database